# How do I find out the make/model of Dell Computer components (before I buy it)?

Tags: components

Dell.com lets you configure your own computer (nice) but doesn't tell you the specific make/model of the components so you can't look at benchmarks/reviews, etc. for them. (Maybe that economical SSD drive is complete cr*p )

Comment: You could start a chat session with Dell before you place the order, or call them and ask them about model specific information. If they don't have any more information than what's already on the website then I'm afraid there's no way telling what's inside. The only thing they do disclose on the website is the model number of the CPU.

Answer (score 5):

Often they (larger OEMs) won't tell you ahead of time because they want to be able to swap makes/model of individual parts without changing the over-all system.  This allows them to buy whatever is cheapest and most available at the time, but still put out the same "model".

So a pretend Dell model like "Dell Optiplex with a 500GB drive" might have a 500GB drive by Seagate today, and tomorrow it might be a Western digital, but it's still a "Dell Optiplex with a 500GB drive".

If you want specific parts, I'd suggest buying the parts and assemble your own system (or go to a whitebox-building computer store and get them to assemble you one).